# Is the t-test miscalibrated in R?

Tags: r, t-test

When the null hypothesis is true, the p-value of a test should have the standard uniform distribution. Here is what I get with `t.test(...)` in R using two Gaussian samples of size 5.

```
set.seed(123)
p.val <- replicate(n=100000, t.test(rnorm(n=5), rnorm(n=5))$p.value)
hist(p.val, breaks=50)
```

[image]

You can see that there is a deficit of low p-values. Below is what I get with somewhat bigger samples of size 10.

```
set.seed(123)
p.val <- replicate(n=100000, t.test(rnorm(n=10), rnorm(n=10))$p.value)
hist(p.val, breaks=50)
```

[image]

The deficit of low p-values is gone. So what happens in the first example? Is there something wrong with `t.test(...)` in R for small-ish sample sizes?

---

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Catalina 10.15.7

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/lib/libRblas.0.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_CA.UTF-8/en_CA.UTF-8/en_CA.UTF-8/C/en_CA.UTF-8/en_CA.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.2.1
```

Comment: Cool question and a +1 from me! How does it in other software? Does Python/SciPy or SAS give a similar result?

Comment: [Here](https://gist.github.com/galenseilis/feaad22200f73b23465eaba1c47533c2) is a Python gist of this simulation.

Comment: What do you consider "small" if 10 is only "small-ish"?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`t.test` performs [Welch's *t*-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch%27s_t-test) if the argument `var.equal` is not explicitly set to `TRUE`. The distribution of the test statistic (under the null hypothesis) in Welch's *t*-test is only approximated by a *t*-distribution and this approximation gets better with increasing sample sizes. Therefore, the result of your simulation is not particularly surprising.

---

*Addendum*
The test statistics in Welch's *t*-test and Student's *t*-test coincide if the two sample sizes $n_1$ and $n_2$ (of group $1$ and $2$, respectively) are equal. Hence, the discrepancy in the (simulated) *p*-value distributions of the two tests (note that the one of Student's *t*-test is uniform on $\left[0,1\right]$) under the null hypothesis is due to the discrepancy between the estimated degrees of freedom $\nu$ in Welch's *t*-test and the degrees of freedom $\tilde\nu=2\left(n-1\right)$ in Student's *t*-test, where $n=n_1=n_2$.

It is easy to see that, if $n_1=n_2$, the estimated degrees of freedom are given by
$$
\nu = \frac{\left(n-1\right)\left(s_1^2 + s_2^2\right)^2}{s_1^4+s_2^4}
= \frac{\left(n-1\right)\left(s_1^4 + s_2^4 + 2s_1^2s_2^2 \right)}{s_1^4+s_2^4},
$$
where $s_1$ and $s_2$ are the Bessel-corrected sample standard deviations.

By the [AM–GM inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means) and the non-negativity of sample standard deviations, $2s_1^2s_2^2 \leq s_1^4 + s_2^4$ (with equality only if $s_1 = s_2$) and $2s_1^2s_2^2 \geq 0$, therefore $n-1 \leq \nu \leq 2\left(n-1\right)=\tilde\nu$. This shows that the estimated degrees of freedom can only underestimate (or$-$but almost never$-$coincide with) the true degrees of freedom in the given situation, which leads to the conservative *p*-values seen in your simulation.
This behavior is nicely illustrated in [Thomas Lumley's answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/593191/136579).

Since $s_1$ will tend to be closer to $s_2$ with increasing $n$, we can also see that $\nu$ will tend to be closer to $\tilde\nu$ as $n$ increases. Additionally, for a fixed difference $\nu - \tilde\nu$ in degrees of freedom of two *t*-distributions, their PDFs become increasingly similar with increasing $\nu$, and $\nu$ increases with $n$ in our case. This explains the improvement of the approximation and hence the *p*-value distribution with increasing group/total sample size.

Comment: Amazing, thanks for the clarification! I was wondering if you could point to a didactic source explaining the rationale of the df correction. Wikipedia is very laconic. That would be very useful for everyone.

Comment: This link: https://statisticaloddsandends.wordpress.com/2020/07/03/welchs-t-test-and-the-welch-satterthwaite-equation/ describes how Satterthwaite derived it, to match the variance of $\hat\sigma^2$.  Welch derived it differently: https://www.jstor.org/stable/2332510

Comment: @gui11aume One way to derive $\nu$ is to assume that the distribution of $\nu\left(\frac{s_1^2}{n_1}+\frac{s_2^2}{n_2}\right)/\left(\frac{\sigma_1^2}{n_1}+\frac{\sigma_2^2}{n_2}\right)$ can be approximated by a $\chi^2\left(\nu\right)$ distribution. Equate the two variances, solve for $\nu$, and replace population by sample variances. This goes back to Satterthwaite ([1941](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02288586), [1946](https://doi.org/10.2307/3002019)) and is, e.g, detailed in [this](https://hsu.edu/uploads/pages/lloyd_5.pdf) paper in the section "Derivation of the degrees of freedom formula".

Comment: Thanks! I see the logic now. Quite intuitive actually.

Comment: @gui11aume I'm glad I could help!

Answer (score 23):

Following up on @statmerkur's correct answer: first, here's what you get with `var.equal=TRUE`
[image]

which is well calibrated.
Second, here's the distribution of estimated degrees of freedom for the Welch t-test

[image]

As you can see, the estimated degrees of freedom are typically near 8, but occasionally quite a bit smaller. When the df is smaller, the p-value will be conservative.

Finally, here's the p-value distribution separately for estimated df>7 and $\leq 7$

[image]

Comment: Nice illustration (+1). I've added a theoretical justification for that to my answer.

Comment: [Here](https://gist.github.com/galenseilis/c36bb3f7727586dbe8eaad4cb1a38a6e) is a Python gist producing similar histograms.