# Which test should I use? paired t-tests or ANOVA?

Tags: t-test, spss, paired-data

For my statistical analysis, I have two methods and a specific bone to be measured by both methods.
Multiple variables should be measured for both bones like height, depth, width, angles, etc. So I want to know which test is the best for comparing the mean difference between these two samples.

Comment: What are you supposed to test?

Comment: I suppose to measure the mean difference.

Comment: Is there only one bone, or many ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both are applicable they give the same p-values as the F test used in anova is equivalent to the t-test -- see [this](https://canovasjm.netlify.app/2018/10/29/when-does-the-f-test-reduce-to-t-test/), [this](https://likan.info/en/post/2017-05-23-f-statistic-and-t-square-are-identical/) or [this](https://eric.ed.gov/?id=ED215894) for mathematical proof -- a commenter mentioned that this equality is only strictly true if the t test is performed under the equal variances assumption by using the `var.equal=TRUE` t.test argument although the p values are still the same to several digits even if not in the examples below.  We show both unpaired and paired examples. Using the `sleep` data that comes with R we see that in the first (unpaired) example below they both give a p-value of 0.07919 .

```r
t.test(extra ~ group, sleep, var.equal = TRUE)
##
##        Two Sample t-test
##
## data:  extra by group
## t = -1.8608, df = 18, p-value = 0.07919
## alternative hypothesis: true difference in means between group 1 and 
## group 2 is not equal to 0
## 95 percent confidence interval:
##  -3.363874  0.203874
## sample estimates:
## mean in group 1 mean in group 2 
##            0.75            2.33 

fm <- lm(extra ~ group, sleep)
anova(fm)
## Analysis of Variance Table
## 
## Response: extra
##           Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value  Pr(>F)  
## group      1 12.482 12.4820  3.4626 0.07919 .
## Residuals 18 64.886  3.6048                  
## ---
## Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

And for a paired test we see that the p-values are both 0.002833 for the t-test and anova F test.  We used a vector, `ones`, for the intercept since the R `anova` software does not produce F tests for an intercept only model otherwise.

```r
t.test(extra ~ group, sleep, paired = TRUE, var.equal = TRUE)
##
##         Paired t-test
##
## data:  extra by group
## t = -4.0621, df = 9, p-value = 0.002833
## alternative hypothesis: true mean difference is not equal to 0
## 95 percent confidence interval:
##  -2.4598858 -0.7001142
## sample estimates:
## mean difference 
##           -1.58 


ones <- rep(1, 10)
fm <- lm(diff(extra, 10) ~ ones + 0, sleep)
anova(fm)
## Analysis of Variance Table
##
## Response: diff(extra, 10)
##           Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)   
## ones       1 24.964 24.9640  16.501 0.002833 **
## Residuals  9 13.616  1.5129                    
## ---
## Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Peter Dalgaard suggested this more elegant equivalent R code for the paired case which also gets around the fact that the anova function in R does not automatically produce F tests for the intercept.

```r
fit1 <- lm(diff(extra,10) ~ 1, sleep)
fit0 <- update(fit1, ~ -1)
anova(fit0, fit1)
##
## Analysis of Variance Table
##
## Model 1: diff(extra, 10) ~ 1 - 1
## Model 2: diff(extra, 10) ~ 1
##   Res.Df    RSS Df Sum of Sq      F   Pr(>F)   
## 1     10 38.580                                
## 2      9 13.616  1    24.964 16.501 0.002833 **
## ---
## Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Comment: sleep data doesn't contain multiple variables. Are the results for multiple variables stay the same?

Comment: It is not really clear to me what the setup of your problem is from the very brief description but I thought it worthwhile to point out that the t test and anova F test are basically equivalent.  If you have multiple t tests or F tests then you have a multiple comparisons problem and t;hat is the issue rather than t test vs anonva.   Search for *multiple comparisons in R* to find information assuming you are using R.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Welch's *t*-test is not equivalent to the standard *F*-test for equality of population means (see, e.g., my answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/593172/136579)).

Comment: @G.Grothendieck In your first example you are not using the unpaired two-sample *t*-tests with equal-variance assumption (for which you would have to set the `var.equal` argument of `t.test` to `TRUE`) but Welch's *t*-test. If you have a closer look at your output, you can see that the *p*-value of the *F*- and *t*-test in that example are *not* identical. You can see in my answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/593172/136579) why this is the case.

Comment: You saying that the R code should have specified `t.test(..., var.equal=TRUE)` in order that the t and F statistics be the same.  I have fixed that now.  For the examples here there were no practical differences in the answers either way but  in any case now the p values are the same to all displayed digits.

Comment: I didn't say that "this is only true if the t test is performed under the equal variances assumption". There are also *F*-tests for equality of population means that don't assume equal population variances. What matters is to use *t*- and *F*-tests that correspond to each other when you claim equivalence.

Comment: What is claimed equal is equal and I have provided the code and the links to the proofs.  If you want to split hairs and refer to other code and tests out of context then I don't see that as particularly relevant. Obviously you need to have corresponding tests and the ones shown are.

Comment: I don't want to split hairs and don't disagree with what you call equivalent in your *edited* answer. However, I didn't say that *F*- and *t*-tests are only equivalent in the equal-variance setting $-$ they are more generally in the case of 1 (numerator) degree of freedom if corresponding variants are used. My first two comments referred to the `t.test` function. In particular, my second comment was a response to your (now deleted) comment in which you claimed that the *p*-values of `t.test` with `var.equal = FALSE` and `anova` would be "obviously" identical.

Comment: I deleted it because I moved the var.equal to the answer and specifically referred to your comment in the answer.   Also the p values even without var.equal=TRUE are identical to 3 decimal places so please do not try to misrepresent this.