# T-test p-value from lm() function does not equal t.test() function in R

Tags: r, regression, t-test, p-value, lm

I thought the the following code in R should run equivalent t-tests. But the p-value obtained from each method differs. The p-value using lm() is 3.415937e-05 but using t.test() it is 0.0001098368.

Why are p-values different?

```
summary(lm(mpg ~ vs, mtcars))$coefficients -> coefs

as.vector(coefs)[8] -> lm_pvalue

t.test(mpg ~ vs, mtcars)$p.value -> ttest_pvalue
```

Comment: Also see [Is the t-test miscalibrated in R?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/593170/237901). This thread explains what's going on with the t-test.

Comment: Or even just read the help on `t.test`  (`?t.test`) in R, which also explains what the function does and how to get it to do what you wanted instead (see the discussion in the description of the  `var.equal` argument)

Answer (score 3):

If you call t.test and set var.equal = TRUE I think you will find that the outputs agree. By default t.test does the Welch method which allows for the variances to vary. In fact the values of t are not that different but do give rise to the p-values you quote.